# How to work with dynamic variable names?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm setting a local dynamic variable name the following way 
`_local["cracks"..brick.index] = ...`

How than I can access the variable to do for example removeSelf?
what I've tried
`_local["cracks"..brick.index]:removeSelf()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
_local["cracks"..brick.index]:removeSelf()
```

1. indexes `_local` as a table with `"cracks"..brick.index` to obtain a value, call it `t`
2. indexes `t` as a table with `"removeSelf"` to obtain another value, call it `m`
3. invokes `m` as a method in `t`, which is like calling `m(t)`

For that to work, you would have had to do something like this:

```
_local["cracks"..brick.index] = 
{ 
    removeSelf = function(self)
        --do something with self, 
        --which refers to the table that removeSelf is a member of (the {})
        return --something if wanted 
    end 
}
```

Normally, methods are defined with the `function t:m() end` syntax that implicitly declares the `self` parameter. But, you can't do that without an actual `t` variable, which in this case there isn't.

Or, explicitly

```
local tabl = {}
function tabl:removeSelf()
    --do something with self, 
    --which refers to the table that removeSelf is a member of (tabl)
    return --something if wanted 
end 

_local["cracks"..brick.index] = tabl
```

Add more code to your question if this doesn't explain what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

No. You are doning it wrong. Here is how you should do it:

```
local myTable = {}
myTable[brick.index] = image
```

then you can access it:

```
myTable[brick.index]:removeSelf()
```